# Creating developer provisioning profile but showing ineligible

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

By mistake I removed the existing developer provisioning profile. So I am trying to create a new developer provisioning profile but each time it is showing ineligible.

Role of my user in the team is agent. App id, adhoc, and distribution provisioning profiles are created under that team with my ID which is working fine. I downloaded all developer and distribution certificates also. But in my keychain I found private key missing for the developer certificate but present for distribution certificate.

At the time of creation of the developer provisioning profile I am selecting all the available signing certificate and all the device ids. In my Xcode project when I am trying to select the developer provisioning profile, which is showing ineligible, I am getting the error message:

> "Provisioning profile 'dev_provisioning_profile' doesn't include signing certificate 'iPhone Developer:'. No certificate matching 'iPhone Developer: ' for team 'team_name'.

What should I do to create valid developer provisioning profile?

Comment: if anyone use {N} just run `tns prepare ios --provision {uuid}` and read more from [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2436)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should delete the developer certificate that does not have a private key especially if there are multiple instances with the same identity. Also an easy way to solve this may be to uncheck then check the Automatically manage signing option in the project settings.

Comment: Yes there are multiple developer certificates with the same identity that does not have a private key and I deleted all those and kept only those developer certificates which has private key.
Then again tried to create new developer provisioning profile with each developer certificate available in developer account but each time it is showing ineligible. I can't understand why can't I create eligible developer provisioning profile.

Comment: You may want to clear all certs from keychain, clear all certs from Xcode, then download latest certs from Xcode then finally install them to keychain. Did you try the auto sign?

Answer (score 6):

Finally solved the issue. Just writing the steps. Not so sure that these are the exact steps but worked for me, may be helpful to others-

1. Delete the developer certificate that does not have a private key.
2. Then first check then uncheck the Automatically manage signing option in the project settings with selecting team.
3. Select provisioning profile in the project settings.
4. Delete the provisioning profile from machine.
5. Sign in developer account and edit the provisioning profile selecting all available developer certificates
6. Download the provisioning profile and add to XCODE.

By following these steps the provisioning profile becomes eligible and working fine.

Comment: can I still use automatically signing?